# Elastic Search TransportClient

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am using `ElasticSearch` Java client to query elastic search. I am initializing transport client every time I have to make a call. Is this the right way or should I initialize once during the start of the application and close it at shutdown.

Following is the code to initialize client

```
 Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder().put("cluster.name", Config.getEsClusterName()).put("client.transport.ignore_cluster_name", true).build();
 Client esClient = new TransportClient(settings).addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(Config.getEsHost(), Config.getEsPort()));
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The elasticsearch Java client is multithreaded and each new instance has a large overhead.

This should be instantiated once at the start of your program and shared across all callers.

Best Regards

Answer (score 4):

I created a github repository for usage of java elasticsearch transport client[with singleton design pattern].. please ..make use of it.[refer](https://github.com/sidharthancr/elasticsearch-java-client)

Answer (score 0):

TransportClient maintains a pool of connections inside, they'll be kept alive during the entire life cycle of the TransportClient object.

So you should use a static to store the TransportClient object, or implement a singleton class that handles the connection. The rest of your code will communicate with this class only.