# Elastic Search Transport Client stale connections

Tags: java, elasticsearch, database-connection, connection-pooling

When using Transport Client, are there any issues with the connections going stale? Do I have to create a new instance of the transport client every request? Should I reuse the same Transport Client, and if so what is the best practice for making sure the client doesn't lose its connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my experience it is better to define once. I have not seen any issues even if ES goes down and comes back. So look like internally ES takes care of the connection.

I think this question is duplicate on 
[Elastic Search TransportClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24025065/elastic-search-transportclient)

Comment: You're right it looks like a document. I think my question is a bit more searchable both from the title and tags. Let me know if you think I should still delete it though

Comment: I dont think we have to delete your question. The question is more clearer than the other one. So I think it should be useful.